# How to set the navigation links to current page in bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular application in that application I have created the navigation links for home,about,notifications,logout.

But when I am clicking the home link it will go to login page

But I have to remain in the current page only when we click on the home and notifications.

**component.html**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm   navbar-light bg-light " id="navcolor">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <img src="assets/img/bbbs.jpeg" height="40" width="40" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;opacity: 0.6;">ADDS
    &nbsp;
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link" id="col"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home fa-lg"></i>Home <span
              class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/About" class="nav-link" href="#" id="col"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i> About</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="#" class="nav-link" id="col"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i> Notifications&nbsp;<span
              id="notificount">

            </span></a>


      </ul>
      <div class="social-part">
        <a href="#" id="col" style="color: black;" (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Now my requirement is when I click the home or notification it has to remain in the current page it self.

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: If you omit `routerLink="#"` in your anchor tags it won't navigate to any place and stay at the current page

Comment: Not working,because it is having href="#" that's why it is going to other page.How can I overcome this.Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think u might have a route guard in place which re-directs to login page,
check for "canActivate" attribute in your app.route.ts or app.module.ts as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamComponent,
        canActivate: [CanActivateTeam] ==> authenticates & re directs to login page if added so
      }
    ])
  ]
```

Comment: No,I have not placed the route for the login page.My question is if I click on the home it has to be in the current page it self irrespective of the routes.

Comment: do you want to stay in same page without activating any route ?

Comment: Yes,absolutely.Can you help me regarding this

Comment: you can remove the routerlinks & href ="" if thats what u wish for! since the 'nav-link' will still show them as links with not path to re-direct to

Answer (score 0):

What is router path of the current page? For example, If The router is following:

```
{ 
  path: 'home',
  component: HomeComponent
}
```

You have to change routerlink to this:

```
<a routerLink="/home" ...></a>
```

Comment: But I have the admin page and used the dashboard component data in admin component  as <app-dashboard></app-dashboard> aprt from that I ahve created some more data for admin page.So finally nav links also coming from the dashboard that's why when I click on that home link it will automatically go to dashboard page.But I want to stay within the page only when we click on that home,notification links

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to stick the navbar on the top and change pages below. If that's what you want then place that navbar tag in a component and using a selector place it on the top of router-outlet tag.
Step 1: Create a component.
Step 2: In app.component.html where you placed  there you call the created navbar component on top of it.

```
<!--In your case the component you created may have different selector-->
<nav-bar><nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```